# Prove that $1 + \alpha < e^{\alpha}$ $\forall$ $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Stopped at this step:

$\alpha = \frac{m}{n}$, $m = n \alpha$

$e > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

$e^{\alpha} > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n \alpha} = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{m}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Taylor expansion for $e^x$? Or use monotonicity of $f(x)=e^x-1-x$.

Comment: Not true for $\alpha =0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha = \frac{m}{n}$, $m = n \alpha$

$e > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

$e^{\alpha} > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n \alpha} = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{m} \geqslant 1 + \frac{m}{n} = 1+\alpha$, using $(1+x)^n \geqslant 1 + nx$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What is the minimum of $f(\alpha )=e^\alpha -1-\alpha $ ? (where $\alpha \in\mathbb R$)